# How to retrieve meta from celery backend storage

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am using celery with a flask app to launch some background tasks, I am using mongoDB as a backend.

I would like to store in the backend some information about the task being launch and then be able to retrieve it.

I believe the key is in the use of `self.update_state(state= ..., meta = {})` where meta is my custom information. However I do not find anything working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we assume you have a task like this:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def counter(self):
    for i in xrange(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.update(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current': i})
    return {'status': 'complete'}
```

and you have flask route like this:

```
@app.route('/count/')
def count_100():
    """
        this starts a counter task and returns a response immediately
    """ 
    task = counter.delay()
    # this will return an empty json object with 202 http code status
    # which means requests is still in progress and a Location header
    return jsonify(), 202, dict(Location=url_for('status', task_id=task.id))
```

and finally your task status route is something like this:

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
...
@app.route('/status/<task_id>/')
def status(task_id):
    task = AsyncResult(task_id) # retrieving the task we started
    if task.state == 'PROGRESS':
        response = {
            'state': task.state,
            'current': task.info.get('current', 0)
        }
    return jsonify(response)
```